# Clear mathematical way to cast int value to 0 or 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Maybe it's too trivial question but I can't find answer if there is a some more elegant way to cast `int` value to `0` or `1` without using condition or type casting?
Now I have only following variants and both are ugly:

```
x = 5
a = some_int_value * (1 if x > 0 else 0)
b = some_int_value * int(bool(x))
```

**ADDED**
`x` is a non-negative value.

Comment: So you want every nonzero to 1 and only int-zero to 0, right?

Comment: Note: Those two ways are not equivalent if `x < 0`

Comment: why do u multiply? you should return `some_int_value ` or `0`

Comment: Will you ever need to deal with negatives?

Comment: Well, for one, you do not need to cast back to `int`: `b = some_int_value * bool(x)`. Elegant enough?

Comment: @tobias_k, sorry, my mistake... `x` can't be less than `0`.

Comment: I would do `a = some_int_value if x else 0`

Comment: @tobias_k, I know that it's not required to do the second cast to `int` back but it still will be when python will dedicate type. I mean a some way without condition and casting.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, `some_int_value` is a some `int` value including `0`, negative and positive values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way without functions, casting, or conditionals, but *with* comparisons:

```
d = some_int_value * (x > 0)
```

However, in terms of readability, a ternary `... if ... else ...` should probably be preferred.

---

If you want a purely mathematical way, you can use exponentiation with *1 - 0<sup>x</sup>*, since `0**x` is `1` *only if* `x == 0` and `0` otherwise. But whether that is in any way *clear* is another question. (Also note that this gives a division-by-zero for `x < 0`, but you said that you don't have those.)

```
>>> x = 5
>>> 1 - 0**x
1
>>> x = 0
>>> 1 - 0**x
0
```

Comment: You are right `if...else` is useless in this case but I looked for some pure computing way not based on casting or conditions

Comment: @Шах Why useless? What's wrong with `some_int_value if x > 0 else 0`, as already suggested in comments?

Comment: yap, thank you very much. It's that I was needed. I know it's not fast way but I just wanted to get how to make it

Answer (score 4):

To paraphrase your condition, `x` can be `0` or a value larger than `0`. If `x > 0`, you want to use the value `some_int_value`, otherwise you want `0` (which is identical to `x`). Then do:

```
c = x and some_int_value
```

If `x` is `0`, i.e. *falsey*, the `and` expression returns `x`. If `x` is *truthy* (non-zero), it returns `some_int_value`.

Arguably even more comprehensible would be:

```
d = some_int_value if x > 0 else 0
```

Or:

```
e = 0
if x > 0:
    e = some_int_value
```

Comment: Nice, but not sure if this qualifies as "clear" (maybe it's just me, but somehow I always find this (ab)use of `and` much harder to grasp than for `or`)

Comment: At least it's less confusing than seemingly non-sequitur multiplication I'd say.

Comment: Thank you, honestly, it's not that I looked for  but it's interesting solution

Comment: might be more confusing to grasp, but in terms of the question: no casting, no conditions, just one operator! very neat!